# How do I get zeromq PUSH/PULL to work on windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, zeromq

Here are the "sender" and "receiver" I am using.

sender.py

```
import time

import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
sender = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
sender.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")

c = 0
while True:
    sender.send_json(c)
    print "Sent {}".format(c)
    c += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

reciever.py

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
receiver = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
receiver.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")

while True:
    m = receiver.recv_json()
    print m
```

When I start the receiver then start the sender nothing is written to stdout on the receiver's cmd (I am trying to get this to work on windows 7).  I've added inbound and outbound exceptions to the firewall for port 5557 and running `netstat -an` doesn't show anything running on port 5557. Lastly I am using zmq 2.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `sender.py` you should write `sender.bind`, not `sender.connect`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. A caveat, I believe my code is likely to suffer from the "[slow joiner](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all)" issue.